# Exception encountered while creating session

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

#Everythime I am trying AWS Glue interactive notebook,I am getting this error..Please help somebody fix this

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
  
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
```

#I am unable to start the session

Comment: What is the error? You mention one, but I can't see it in the information you have provided.